# Does removing item from Hashmap open it to GC?

Tags: java, memory-management, concurrenthashmap

Does calling .remove() on a ConcurrentHashMap object open that object to be garbage collected?  The Javadocs say a lot about removing the mapping but never mentions what happens to the object.

I'm having a bit of a memory leak somewhere and I'm wondering if this might be it.  Should I nullify objects in my hashmap before removing?

Comment: Nullifying objects never does anything in Java, and you should never bother with it.  Objects will be garbage collected when there's no more references to them, and removing an object from a map removes the reference to the object from the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Removes a single instance of the specified element from this
>   collection, if it is present (optional operation). More formally,
>   removes an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null   : o.equals(e)),` if
>   the collection contains one or more such elements.

so as `e==null` it becomes eligible for GC, We do not achieve anything by Nullifying it ever in java.